# Calculating anomaly score for Anomaly detection using One-Class SVM

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I have a question about Calculating anomaly score for Anomaly detection using One-Class SVM. My question is that: How can I calculate it using  decision_function(X), just the way I calculate anomaly score in Isolation forest?
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

In Isolation Forests, anomaly score is a measure of the deviation of average length of the path required to single out a particular observation from the average length of path required to single out a "normal" observation

The average here is taken over all the different trees that are used. Since SVM is not an ensemble method - this notion of anomaly score does not directly apply.

One way, and I don't know how statistically/scientifically sound this is, of measuring an anomaly score is to build multiple SVM classifiers based on a subset of predictors. You could then use the percentage of times a particular point is classified as an outlier as a proxy for an anomaly score.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use `decision_function()` as the measure of anomaly score in one class SVM.

Have a look at this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-oneclass-py), you might get better understanding.

```py
clf.decision_function(X_test)
# returns the signed distance to the separating hyperplane.
# Signed distance is positive for an inlier and negative for an outlier.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but any example on how to calculate anomaly score from calculating  the decision_function()?

Comment: I have given sample command in my answer, but go through the example link, which has more explanation about `OneClassSVM`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue by default scikit implementation does *NOT* provide an anomally score.

A way to tackle the issue is to use the decision_function (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.decision_function) but with the following way :

```
anomaly_metric[i] = max_value_decision_fn - decision_fn[i]
```

where i is the i-th data point.

sources: https://activisiongamescience.github.io/2015/12/23/Unsupervised-Anomaly-Detection-SOD-vs-One-class-SVM/#sklearn-Users-Beware

[How to calculate AUC for One Class SVM in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022081/how-to-calculate-auc-for-one-class-svm-in-python)