# How can we calculate anomaly score using decision_function(X) One-Class-SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I want to know how can I calculate anomaly score using decision_function(X) in One-Class SVM on my own data-set.

I have studied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956538/calculating-anomaly-score-for-anomaly-detection-using-one-class-svm?rq=1) post and also have seen [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-oneclass-py) example:

Now I want to put my own data-set in the example given above. How is it possible for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply more negative the decision function output is, more anomalous the datapoint is.

Refer [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/svm/classes.py#L1201):

> Signed distance to the separating hyperplane. 
>   Signed distance is positive for an inlier and negative for an outlier.

Comment: Thanks Respected @ai_learning, If I have following parameters x=-45.67, y=-76.11 and Distance=88.77 than how can I apply decision_funcation(X) on it to find anomaly score. Could you please elaborate with some code.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand your question. Is your input data is two dimensional? can you add some reproducible example of your oneClassSVM model?

Comment: Sorry if i could not explain my question. Yes my data is two dimensional, parameters x=-45.67, y=-76.11 and distance=88.77 is one row of my data set. I want to calculate anomaly score.I need help that what I should have for calculating anomaly score other than these parameters and what will be the python code using decision_function(X)